# Is there a way to copy a range and exclude a cell/column in the loop?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first project using Excel-VBA. I've figured out how to use VBA code to do most of what I've wanted. I'm now trying to copy data to a new cell, and then I want to copy a range, but not copy down the data of new cell and leave it blank below. I've only been able to leave the copied data in it's exact place and not move down with the range copies. I don't know if it's possible to do what I want, or if I just don't know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub AddHeader()
    Range("CA1").Formula = "Stay Date"
End Sub

=====================================

Sub CellCopy()
    Range("H2:H4000").Copy Range("CA2")
End Sub

=====================================

Sub CopyData()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "P")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "BZ")).Copy
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "BZ")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

=====================================

Sub RunAllMacros()
    AddHeader
    CellCopy
    CopyData
End Sub
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to do this?

Comment: The CellCopy is duplicating the data I want from "H2:H4000" to "CA2" down. Then I'm duplicating the data down "X" times based on cell "P". The issue is, if I include cell "CA2" in the range copy it duplicates that as well. I'm trying to duplicate the rows, but not duplicating column CA and leaving blank cells instead. They way I have it now, it would duplicate the data in "CA" if I included it in the CopyData range. If I leave it out, it doesn't move the information down and just stays in the exact cell position. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could copy the range.value to a variant array, set the value of the particular element of your array related to that column to "", then insert a row to the desired location and print the modified variant array to your inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear but if I understand correctly, you want to:

1. Repeat each row in your worksheet `n` times (where `n` is read from the worksheet itself and each row has its own `n` value).
2. There are certain columns you want to exclude from being repeated.

I would add that:

- It might be better to loop in reverse order (so that row insertions do not affect the iterator/variable keeping track of loop progress).
- Have you considered copying the entire row (`Range.EntireRow`) and then using `Range.Clear` to clear those columns which you didn't want repeated?
- It's always good to include an example of input and expected output. Otherwise, it's difficult for the responder to verify their own answer.

The code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddHeader(ByVal someSheet As Worksheet)
    someSheet.Range("CA1").Formula = "Stay Date"
End Sub

Private Sub CellCopy(ByVal someSheet As Worksheet)
    someSheet.Range("H2:H4000").Copy someSheet.Range("CA2")
End Sub

Private Sub RunAllMacros()

    Dim sheetToModify As Worksheet
    Set sheetToModify = ActiveSheet ' Better to replace with something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    AddHeader sheetToModify
    CellCopy sheetToModify
    CopyData sheetToModify
End Sub

Private Sub CopyData(ByVal someSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = someSheet.Cells(someSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = lastRow To 2 Step -1 ' Presume you want to skip headers?

        Dim numberOfTimesToRepeatRow As Variant
        numberOfTimesToRepeatRow = someSheet.Cells(rowIndex, "P") ' Will need to -1 as count includes the row being copied.

        If IsGreaterThanOne(numberOfTimesToRepeatRow) Then
            With someSheet.Range("A" & rowIndex, "CA" & rowIndex)
                .Copy
                .Offset(1).Resize(numberOfTimesToRepeatRow - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

                ' Have to repeat/re-evaluate (cannot use With or
                ' object reference since rows have been inserted)
                .Offset(1).Resize(numberOfTimesToRepeatRow - 1).Columns("CA").Clear
            End With
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Function IsGreaterThanOne(ByVal someValue As Variant)
    ' Dedicated function to reduce indentation in caller.
    ' Returns True if value is numeric AND greater than 1 (else
    ' False).
    ' Separate IF statements since no short-circuit
    ' evaluation -- meaning non-numeric values could otherwise
    ' cause type mismatch error.
    If IsNumeric(someValue) Then
        If someValue > 1 Then
            IsGreaterThanOne = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The code above keeps the value in column `CA` for only the original rows -- and not for the newly inserted rows. In the other words, there are blanks in column `CA` of the newly inserted rows.

Hope that makes sense and gives you some idea on how to achieve this. If I've misunderstood, you can let me know.